# Mobile: scroll horizontally inside parent div and add external side gradients on one or both (left, right) sides

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

Here is my page http://mytest37.kissr.com/1.html  where the list can be scrolled horizontally if you switch your Google Chrome browser to the mobile mode or visit from the smartphone.

How to modify the code so that the 15px more pixels appears to the left with a gradient effect (so that the left padding becomes 50px-15px = 35px), if scrolled to the left.
And the same to the right: 15 more pixels of the list (with a white gradient effect) will get displayed to the right, if some more data is beside the right side.

As result, for the long list, the page has the right additional 15px on load. Once we start to scroll to the left, additional 15px (with a gradient effect) immediately appear to the left.

I believe it can't be achieved with css only. Can this be done with vanilla JS? But how?

P.S. jQuery solution is also acceptable (if no vanilla js options).
Thank you.

The code below is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">


<style>
.wrapper-wrapper {padding: 50px;}

.wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: auto;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.wrapper .container {
    max-width: none;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: max-content;
    
    border: 7px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}   
    
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; 
}
 ul {
    clear: both; padding: 0px; list-style: none; margin: 0;
    
    font-size: 30px;
}
li {
    float: left; border: 3px solid red;padding: 30px 0;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-wrapper" id="ddd">
    <div class="wrapper" id="ccc">
        <div class="container" id="bbb">
            <ul class="" id="aaa">
                <li>This</li>
                <li>ul</li>
                <li>can</li>
                <li>be</li>
                <li>scrolled</li>
                <li>horizontally</li>
                <li>in</li>
                <li>the</li>
                <li>mobile</li>
                <li>mode</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
                <li>hahaha</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

</script>


</body>
</html>
```